# google doesn't want to be innerred (XPCOM)

Tags: javascript, mozilla, xpcom

I'm trying to make an firefox extension. Why when I want to use document.body.innerHTML = data; in new opened tab, it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
function change() {


//Open google in new Tab and select it
tab=gBrowser.addTab("http://www.google.com");
gBrowser.selectedTab=tab;

//Create nslFile object
var path="/home/foo/notify.txt"
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath(path);

//Put file content into data variable
var data = "";
var fstream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"].
                        createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileInputStream);
var cstream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-input-stream;1"].
                        createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIConverterInputStream);
fstream.init(file, -1, 0, 0);
cstream.init(fstream, "UTF-8", 0, 0); // you can use another encoding here if you wish

let (str = {}) {
  cstream.readString(-1, str); // read the whole file and put it in str.value
  data = str.value;
}
cstream.close(); // this closes fstream



//change content of google page by file content
document.body.innerHTML = data;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to change the content document, right?  Given your code, `document` points to the XUL window (or the browser in your case), so you are trying to change that.  You should be getting an error about accessing `body` on it since it won't exist.  ([Make sure you've enabled chrome errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment).)  What you really want is `content.document.body.innerHTML`.